# D3 get previous element in .data()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How can I get the value of the previous element of the dataset passed to `.data()` in d3?

I know in a callback I cant do something like

`function(d,i) { console.log(d, i); })`

for example, to print the data element and its index to the console. But how can i reference the previous element?

Like `d[i-1]` or something?

Comment: The below answer is quite involved. Did you try setting d equal to a variable, operating a callback on it, then updating the variable value with each d increment?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can get the value of previous element like this.

```
var texts = svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("x",function(d){ return d.x; })
    .attr("y",function(d){ return d.y; })
    .text(function(d){ return d.name; });

texts.attr(...,function(d,i){
         ......
         var prevData = texts.data()[i-1]; //check whether i>0 before this code
         .......
     });
```

Here is a small example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q567s/76/) , Mouse over the texts to see the functionality.

Answer (score 9):

There is no built in way to do it, but you can achieve it in all kinds of ways, including

Scope:

```
var data = ['a','b','c','d']
d3.select('.parent').selectAll('.child')
  .data(data)
.enter()
  .append('div')
  .attr('class', 'child')
  .text(function(d,i) {
    return "previous letter is " + data[i-1];
  });
```

Linking (works even if they're Strings, as in this example):

```
var data = ['a','b','c','d']
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { data[i].previous = data[i-1]; }
d3.select('.parent').selectAll('.child')
  .data(data)
...
.text(function(d,i) {
  return "previous letter is " + d.previous
});
```

Via the parent node (Experimental):

```
var data = ['a','b','c','d']
d3.select('.parent').selectAll('.child')
  .data(data)
...
.text(function(d,i) {
  var parentData = d3.select(this.parentNode).selectAll('.child').data();
  // NOTE: parentData === data is false, but parentData still deep equals data
  return "previous letter is " + parentData[i-1];
});
```

Related to the last example, you can even try to find the sibling DOM node immediately preceding this node. Something like

```
...
.text(function(d,i) {
  var previousChild = d3.select(this.parentNode).select('.child:nth-child(' + i + ')')
  return "previous letter is " + previousChild.datum();
})
```

but the last two can fail in all kinds of ways, like if the DOM nodes aren't ordered the same as `data`, or if there are other unrelated DOM nodes within the parent.

Comment: isnt this answer better? why the other one has more upvotes? ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @Ammar, It depends I guess. The option in the other answer is more concise and likely easier to understand. If there’s not a lot of data involved it’s just fine. If data however is a long array, it can get quite unperformant, because d3 has to iterate over all elements in the selection and gather each one’s datum. And note that if data has n elements then the relatively expensive call to .data() will occur n times(!).